# MKMapのピンの吹き出しに表示するUIButtonの画像を変更したい

Tags: ios, objective-c, mapkit

現在コールアウトをクリックすると処理が行われるように、以下のように`mapView:annotationView:calloutAccessoryControlTapped:`に処理を記述しております。

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)annotationView calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control { 
    // 処理
}
```

しかし、pin.rightCalloutAccessoryViewに入れて表示されるボタンの種類は

- UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure（iマーク）
- UIButtonTypeContactAdd（+マーク）

の２種類だけで、UIButtonTypeCustomなどにしても表示されません。

```
pinView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
```

どうすれば、好きなボタンを吹き出しに入れることができ、かつcalloutAccessoryControlTapped:を呼び出せるでしょうか。

Answer (score 1):

おそらく`frame`がゼロになっているので実際には追加されているけど見えない（当然タップもできない）状態になっていると思います。

書かれているように生成して直接代入するのではなく、いったん変数に受けて、`frame`を設定して、必要なら色を変えたり画像を設定するなどすると、好きな見た目のボタンを表示することができます。

```
UIButton *rightButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
rightButton.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 30.0, 30.0); // ここで適当な大きさを指定します

// あとは色を変えたり画像を設定したり好きなように...
rightButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
[rightButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"flag"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
pinView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = rightButton;
```